# Useragent setting in Edge Webdriver

Tags: selenium, microsoft-edge

I am trying to use specific useragent strings for Selenium sessions with the Edge Web Driver.
I cannot find any example parameters/options that support this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to set the user agent string for MS Edge (chromium) browser then you can refer to the example below.

Here, I am using Visual Studio and I have created a Console C# app.

You need to add a reference to **Microsoft.Edge.SeleniumTools** and **Selenium.WebDriver**

[image]

Sample code to set the different user agent string using Selenium Edge web driver:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        var options = new EdgeOptions();
        ptions.UseChromium = true;
        options.BinaryLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe";
        options.AddArgument("--user-agent=mozilla/5.0 (windows nt 10.0; win64; x64; rv:78.0) gecko/20100101 firefox/78.0"); // Here we try to set Firefox user agent...
        var driver = new Microsoft.Edge.SeleniumTools.EdgeDriver(@"D:\D drive backup\selenium web drivers\edgedriver 84.0.522.40", options);
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("file:///D:/Tests/95.html");
}
```

**95.HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   
</head>
<body>

    <script>
        var browser = (function (agent) {
            switch (true) {
                case agent.indexOf("edge") > -1: return "edge";
                case agent.indexOf("edg") > -1: return "chromium based edge (dev or canary)";
                case agent.indexOf("opr") > -1 && !!window.opr: return "opera";
                case agent.indexOf("chrome") > -1 && !!window.chrome: return "chrome";
                case agent.indexOf("trident") > -1: return "ie";
                case agent.indexOf("firefox") > -1: return "firefox";
                case agent.indexOf("safari") > -1: return "safari";
                default: return "other";
            }
        })(window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
        document.body.innerHTML = window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase() + "<br>" + browser;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The code on this page will identify the browser based on the user agent string.

Here, if you run the above HTML page then it will identify the browser correctly.

We will try to launch this page from selenium code after setting the user agent and it will show the browser name that we have set in the user agent string.

Output:

[image]

You can notice that it is launching the MS Edge (Chromium) browser but the web page identifies the browser as Firefox. that proves that our automation code has changed the user agent string.